# Strange URL structure when adding menu item

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

On my self hosted WordPress blog [Florida Psychics](https://floridapsychics.org/) when I add a category into menu, I see strange url pattern. Does anyone know where it's coming from?

I expect it to be /category-name

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6g6D.png)

What is causing it and how do I fix it?

I've custom values in settings
On permalinks I've two customized values

Custom Structure value is /%category%/%postname%.html

Category base has . (dot)

I want the urls to be /category-name/post-name.html and I'm assume above values are correct to give me these url structures.

Answer (score 1):

You have to go to settings, permanent links and there you have the ability to change your url in the format that you want.

Comment: How can you do that? I think It has nothing to do with permalinks?